# How to pass a PictureBox image from a C# Windows Form Application to get used in a MATLAB Function?

Tags: c#, matlab

I am using C# Windows Form application on Visual Studio 2012 and a MATLAB Function on MATLAB R2016a. I need to pass a PictureBox image from the Windows Form Application to a MATLAB Function. I already knew how to connect MATLAB to C# using [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html) as a reference.

But when I would use this method for my case I would get this COMException:

> Error using Brightness
>
> Too many output arguments.

This is my C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace IP_Tasks
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void openImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }

       
    }

    private void openImage2btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox3.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void displayChannelbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the MATLAB instance 
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

        // Change to the directory where the function is located 
        matlab.Execute(@"cd 
         C:\Users\owner\Documents\MATLAB\ChannelBrightness");

        // Define the output 
        object result = null;

        matlab.Feval("Brightness",1,out result,pictureBox1.Image, brightnessChannel.SelectedIndex,brightnessOffsettxt.Text);
        
        object[] res = result as object[]; 

        byte[] data = (byte[]) res[0];
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        // Display result        
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

        pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my MATLAB Function code :

```
function [ result ] = Brightness(Image, Ch, Offset)
newBuf=Image;
if (Ch == 0)
newBuf(:,:,1)= Image(:,:,1)+Offset;
elseif (Ch == 1)
newBuf(:,:,2)= Image(:,:,2)+Offset;
else
newBuf(:,:,3)= Image(:,:,3)+Offset;
end
result=newBuf;

end
```

I tried adding a breakpoint in the C# code to know where the exception occurs and I found out that it occurs in this line:

```
matlab.Feval("Brightness",1,out result,pictureBox1.Image, 
brightnessChannel.SelectedIndex,brightnessOffsettxt.Text);
```

I've used the MATLAB function on MATLAB before and there wasn't any problem with it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The problem is your path contains a space and `cd` interprets it as two separate arguments, while it only accepts one. Replace with `cd 'C:\Users\owner\Documents\MATLAB\Self-Implemented Functions\Channel Brightness'`. Always read error messages and try and understand them. They are there to help you.

Comment: @Naveh I removed the spaces and changed in the number of the outputs in this line from 2 to 1 : 
`matlab.Feval("Brightness",1,out result,pictureBox1.Image, brightnessChannel.SelectedIndex,brightnessOffsettxt.Text);`
 So the exception changed from
 Error using cd

Too many input arguments.  

to

Error using Brightness

too many output arguments.

what number should I change?